# Why (as java docs says)we cannot call execute methods in Statement Interface from the PreparedStatement or CallableStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc, execute

There is a note in all the execute type methods in Statement Interface in the java docs that says

> Note:This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.

But why it is So? I mean `PreparedStatement` is a sub-interface of `Statement`, then why we can't do so? In fact I tried and it worked.

```
    ConnectionSetup setCon = new ConnectionSetup();
    // My own class for increasing readability.
    try{

        setCon.loadDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//loadDriver calls Class.forName.
        con = setCon.setUpConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/odi batsman", "root", "");//setUpConnection asks DriverManager for Connection Object.
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.execute(query);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It worked perfectly fine, the record was entered successfully in the database in spite of the fact that I called execute method (which takes a string as input and inherited from the interface `Statement`) from `PreparedStatement`. So whats going on?

**EDIT** I am just asking that it is written in java docs that we cannot call `execute(string)` from `PreparedStatement` but as it is sub-interface of `Statement`, why we can't?

Comment: If I remember correctly the overloaded version doesn't execute the actual prepared statement with the replaced placeholders. So your query won't work if you have something like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE blub = ?;`. So you need to use this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't ask why you can't use the overloaded version, but the answers will tell you that.

Comment: About your edit: That part in the JavaDoc doesn't mean that one is unable to call it (the compiler won't moan). You just shouldn't do it, because it doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Tom It means query gets executed as if we were using `Statement` object?

Comment: The query gets executed as it is. So `SELECT * FROM table` works, because there is no placeholder in it, but the query in my first comment won't, because the placeholder won't be replaced with an actual value. That's what @dunni tries explain in his (or her) answer.

Comment: @Tom Actually, the apidoc says it should throw an `SQLException` in this case, the specific driver implementation - incorrectly - doesn't do that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wondered why "they" don't override these methods and throw something like a `NotImplementedException`. But since the API requested an exception (which I haven't noticed until now), it is clear that the implementation is wrong. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3):

The fact it worked means that the driver implementation you are using (I guess MySQL Connector/J) doesn't comply with the JDBC 4.1 (or higher) specification. The JDBC API javadoc is not only for users of the API, but also describes the behavior that driver vendors need to implement.

The API doc of the various `execute(String)`, `executeQuery(String)`, etc say:

> `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement, **the method is called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement**

This bolded part was added in JDBC 4.1 (Java 7) to clarify the expected behavior.

There are several reasons for this:

1. Calling one of the `execute...(String)` methods ignores the prepared statement and so it is probably a bug that you called this method. Raising an exception makes clear that you did something wrong.
2. Executing a statement string other than the prepared statement on a statement handle, may on some database systems invalidate the prepared statement, leading to unexpected behavior when you first use `execute...(String)` and subsequently try to execute using `execute...()` and expecting it to use the earlier prepared statement.

In hindsight it was probably a mistake that `Statement`, `PreparedStatement` and `CallableStatement` form an inheritance hierarchy. For backwards compatibility, this can no longer be changed.

Answer (score 2):

What's going on is, that you basically didn't use the PreparedStatement itself, when you called the `execute(String)` method, which means, it didn't use the precompiled SQL stuff, which the PreparedStatement does for you. If you would have parameters in your query and you would have set the parameter values in the PreparedStatement, the `execute(String)` method would ignore these parameters.

Comment: how it ignores? does it call execute(String) that is overloaded from the method execute()?

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace:

```
  ps.execute(query);
```

With:

```
   ps.executeQuery();
```

Because you have already passed the `query` in PreparedStatement  `con.prepareStatement(query)`.